# Separate compress data in two different column

Tags: mysql

I am getting data piled up in only one column and i want to separate the information

This is what im doing:

```
UPDATE `Inventario`.`inventario` 
SET `DESCRIPCION`='MONITOR 17\",,DELL ' 
WHERE `ID`='473';
```

for example DELL should be in another column

Comment: What's the table structure?

Comment: How do i show the table structure??

Comment: Use https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Post the output of `show create table inventario`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple columns in an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE `Inventario`.`inventario` 
SET `DESCRIPCION`='MONITOR 17"',
    `Manufacturer` = 'DELL' 
WHERE `ID`='473';
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `"` inside a string delimited with `'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Inventario.inventario SET DESCRIPCION='MONITOR 17\"', Manufacturer = 'DELL' WHERE ID='473';
```

If your table has the column with the name manufacturer.